# How to use dynamic property in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a `handleInputBlur` function that has a dynamic parameter. Say I have `this.props.user` object like this

```
{ name: 'abc', age: 10 }
```

Then in my UI I can do inline edit, so `handleInputBlur` will get a parameter of name `changeField` which will be an object containing the changed field:

```
{ age: 10 }
```

I still have to pass the entire object back to the backend, how can I replace updated field with my existing object?

I tried this but got an Unexpected Token error:

```
handleInputBlur = (changedField) => {

    const existingUser = this.props.user

    const updatedUserObj = Object.assign({}, existingUser, {
        existingUser[changedField]: changedField
    })
}
```

How can I update the existing user based on `changedField`'s key and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) by surrounding the key that is an expression with brackets so its computed value is used as the key:

```
const key = Object.keys(changedField)[0];
const updatedUserObj = Object.assign({}, existingUser, {
    [key]: changedField[key]
})
```

First, the value of the expression `key` will be computed, then that value would be used as the key. Notice that `Object.keys(changedField)[0]` is the value of `key`. What this does is get the first key inside the `changedField` object -- the property being changed such as `'name'` or `'age'`. Then, that property is set to the value of the new property by accessing the value of the first key in `changedField`.